# MYSQL select from a table where columns match

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to query some DBs for rows where there are duplicates in one column.

*For example*, table `servers` :

```
---------------------
   name  |     ip     
---------------------
| bob    | 10.1.2.3 |
| larry  | 10.1.2.3 |
| sam    | 10.9.9.9 |
| george | 10.9.9.9 |
| bill   | 10.6.6.6 |
| anne   | 10.7.7.7 |
```

I would need my query to pull rows for bob, larry, sam, george since they have a match/duplicate in the second column (in this case, IP addresses).

'bill' and 'anne' would not return, since they have unique IPs

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery to get `ip`s with more than one attached `name` and put result in the `IN` clause :

```
SELECT * 
FROM servers
WHERE ip IN ( SELECT ip 
              FROM servers
              GROUP BY ip 
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f609ef/5)

Or you can use `JOIN`, the logic is the same :

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM servers t1 JOIN (
    SELECT ip 
    FROM servers
    GROUP BY ip 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2 ON t1.ip = t2.ip
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f609ef/6)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM my_table x 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.name <> x.name 
            AND y.ip = x.ip;
```